# Duplicate keys of hash in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I know that hash doesn't store duplicate keys. But I want to know if that default behaviour can be changed according to requirement, Is that possible?
I will give the sample code here

```
keys_array =  [ 'key1', 'key2' ]
values_array = [
       {"A": { "id": "1"   }},
       {"B": { "id": "2"   }}
       ]
results = keys_array.zip(values_array ).to_h
```

Here output is exactly what I wanted
`{"key1"=>{:A=>{:id=>"1"}}, "key2"=>{:B=>{:id=>"2"}}}`

But If the keys get repeated , for example

```
keys_array =  [ 'key1', 'key1' ] in which 'key1' key is repeated,
result will be {"key1"=>{:B=>{:id=>"2"}}}
```

But I want
`{"key1"=>{:A=>{:id=>"1"}}, "key1"=>{:B=>{:id=>"2"}}}`
I know about grouping and all , but it will change the result format
So I don't want to use that

I want this result `{"key1"=>{:A=>{:id=>"1"}}, "key1"=>{:B=>{:id=>"2"}}}` where key1 is a repeated key.
Also please note that these array values are not fixed , its dynamic

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Hash keys are, by definition, unique. Ruby's a fairly dynamic language, so I won't rule out there's a way to do what you want to do, but you may want to think about a way to accomplish your goal without trying to change such fundamental behavior.

Comment: As you already wrote _hash doesn't store duplicate keys_. It is not possible to change this behavior.

Comment: Question: let's assume that it would be possible, how would you access the elements of the hash by key if there are two elements which has exactly same key? Which one would take priority? Or you want to receive them in 'round robin order'? Just use an array to store elements with same key as elements with different index. Question does not make much sense.

Comment: It sounds more like you want a hash of strings to an array of objects. Multiple, identical keys make no sense in the end (even if you did something treacherous to make it look like they were identical) because you wouldn't be able to access them again unless you had the original data to reconstruct the treacherous key, which means you don't need the hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the behavior of a hash with [compare_by_identity](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity).

```
h = Hash.new.compare_by_identity
h["key1"] = 1
h["key1"] = 2
p h #=> {"key1"=>1, "key1"=>2}
```

I've never seen a useful way for this.

Comment: I especially like your closing sentence.

Comment: That's not a duplicate key, though. That's still two different keys.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you are looking for is called a *multimap*. It is, of course, possible to implement one in Ruby. You just have to do it. (Or find a library that does it for you.)

However, neither the core nor the standard library contain a multimap implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No way with a hash, you could use an array of hashes instead:

```
[{"key1"=>{:A=>{:id=>"1"}}}, {"key1"=>{:B=>{:id=>"2"}}}]
```